# Find the Perfect Square

Tags: factorial, square-numbers

I came upon the following question in a recent district math test, and I have no clue how to solve it, besides using a calculator and doing some serious multiplication, but no calculators were available during the test.

> Which of the following numbers is a perfect square?
>
> (A) $\frac {14!15!}{2}$
> (B) $\frac {15!16!}{2}$
> (C) $\frac {16!17!}{2}$
> (D) $\frac {17!18!}{2}$
> (E) $\frac {18!19!}{2}$

Could somebody explain how to solve this problem step by step?

Comment: D is such one jon

Comment: @Semsem How did you get that answer?

Comment: AMC10 by any chance? :3

Answer (score 6):

(D) is equal to $\frac{17!17! \times 18}{2} = 17!17! \times 9 = (17!\times 3)^2$

Comment: And the others can't be split the same way.